# How and in which situation can the word "meditate" be used?

Tags: meaning

*Meditate* has two meanings:

> 1. To think calm thoughts in order to relax or as a religious activity:
> 2. To think seriously about something for a long time:
>
>    [Cambridge definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/meditate)

I can understand the first meaning. But for the second meaning I don't know how or in what situation I can use.

For example, can I use it like this?

> He meditated on the weird attitude of my girlfriend yesterday.

Comment: I wouldn't use ***meditate*** at all in your context, except "semi-faceitiously". It's now so commonly used with the sense of [*Focus one’s mind for a period of time, in silence or with the aid of chanting, **for religious or spiritual purposes or as a method of relaxation***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meditate) that you probably can't avoid those connotations being received by your audience. If you don't want them, choose a different verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, absolutely right, it should be an answer.

Comment: Perhaps "pondered", "puzzled over" or "reflected on".

Comment: @adityasrivastav: Although I haven't actually closevoted, I see questions like this on ELU as essentially off-topic writing advice. To me, ELU is primarily a site where competent speakers analyse/discuss the whys and wherefores of how English works - the needs of *learners* are better addressed on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you meditate**, you focus on your breathing while sitting calmly.
Some people meditate to reduce stress, while others see it as part of their spiritual practice.

Meditate can also be used to describe any **deep thinking** you do, like when you meditate on what to say to a friend who is feeling sad lately.

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/medidate))

> Case in point-
>
> He meditated on the weird attitude of my girlfriend yesterday.

suggested verbs-

> **[introspect](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/introspect)**
> **reflect** on one's own thoughts and feelings

Other types-
mull over, muse, ponder, reflect

Comment: that's how I have known medidation.

Comment: I have never in my life heard anyone use the verb "introspect". If I did, it would seem beyond formal, bordering on _affected_. Same for **omphaloskepsis**    . . http://i.word.com/idictionary/omphaloskepsis

Answer (score 1):

Well, many times, good writers will avoid ambiguity by providing **extra adverbs**. Search at Google Books (not vanilla Google) and you will find this phrase well represented:

[*"meditated **for a long time**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22meditated%20for%20a%20long%20time%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
About 10,800 results

E.g.

> Journey of the Grey Fox People: A Novel - Page 10
>   2001 -
>
> Limping Deer closed his eyes again and **meditated
>   for a long time**, until at last Falling Snow said, “My grandfather,
>   what happened then to the Water People?”

Answer (score -1):

He was taking things too roughly, carelessly. He needed to meditate;  he needed to know the true meaning of his actions.

That is a way it could be used.